# Implementing a Class Array, and reinventing common list methods like append

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

So i'm trying to reinvent the wheel, to gain more a better understanding of lists, but I'm having a tough time thinking how to create an append method.

```py
class Array:

    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    def display(self):
        print(self.array)

    def len(self):
        array = self.array
        count = 0
        for _ in array:
            count += 1
        return count

    def append(self, value):
        array = self.array
        length = self.len()
        array[length] = value
        self.array = array
```

Comment: `self.array.append(value)`...

Comment: How would I actually use this class? The constructor takes no arguments so how would I initialize an array with some elements? Once you decide that, I think it'll be easier for you to be able to figure out how to implement append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size. So when you append an item to array, You need to check if array can accommodate new element or not. If not, you may need to increase its capacity by re-allocating a larger array and copying existing items into the new array.
To reallocate larger array you can use

```
a = [None] * desired_size
```

After this,
1.) copy element from original array to this newly crated array
2.) Put new element in array. You can keep index flag to keep track of last element in the array.

Make sure to modify len() function to return length according to index flag and not the number of elements in array